# Using .confirm() conditional to call jquery .fadeOut() with duration messes up timing of callback

Tags: javascript, jquery, fadeout, timing, confirm

I want to ask the user to confirm deleting a table row.  If they say yes then I want to use the jquery fadeOut() method on the table row with a set duration and a callback to remove the table row after the fade out is complete.

This works fine without the confirm, but the confirm adds odd and inconsistant behavior.  If I hit "ok" right away then it works as expected.  But if I wait for a few seconds before hitting "ok" the fadeout is sometimes skipped, then it takes a few seconds before the row is removed.  It's inconsistant and sometimes I need to do something else (like add a row) first and then I get the buggy behavior (see demonstration link below).  Also if I load the page as an iframe in Facebook for example, I get the problem every time.

I thought it had something to do with asynchronous vs progressive coding and tried to change my code around to call the fadeOut as a callback from a customized confirm function, but this didn't solve anything.  It's likely I didn't do it properly.  Unless requested I won't post that code to avoid confusion.  I also thought it might have something to do with the jquery event queue or the execution context, but I don't know enough to understand/debug that.

So here's a snippet of my code where the problem is.  Note that it works fine if I take out the confirm, or if I take out the fadeOut and just use the remove:

```
// handler to remove question (uses "on" to bind event to future added rows)
        $("#questions").on("click",".removeQuestion", function(){
            if (confirm('Are you sure you want to remove this question?')) {
                // be sure to leave one question to fill in
                if ($("table#questions tr").length == 1) {
                    $(this).parents("td").find("textarea").val('');
                    $(this).parents("td").find("input[type=radio]").attr('checked', false);
                }
                else {
                    $(this).parents("tr").fadeOut(300, function() {
                        $(this).remove();
                    });
                    // update total questions text
                    $(".total_questions").text(function(index, text) {
                      return parseInt(text)-1;
                    });
                }
            }
        });
```

Here's a link to a demo page where you can try to duplicate the error (you might have to play with it some - see notes above about the inconsistencies - the first few tries often work perfectly) and view the whole source:
https://xcitemediacustomfacebookpages.com/hebetsmccallin/admin_test.php

By the way, I'm testing it on Chrome on a Mac.

Thank you for your help!  I've been going in circles on this one and it's so frustrating.

Comment: Anyone else?  One other weird thing I noticed is that sometimes when it gets "stuck" I need to do something like scroll the page before the row will disappear.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue using confirm() with the .animate()-function. It seems that .fadeOut() or in my case .animate() starts counting as soon as confirm() is being called. The solution I found was adding a custom function to the queue:

```
$('#myId').queue(function(){
    $(this).delay(0).dequeue();
}).animate({
    top: 0  // Example
}, 'slow');
```

In your case, this would be:

```
$(this).parents("tr").queue(function(){
    $(this).delay(0).dequeue();
}).fadeOut(300, function() {
    $(this).remove();
});
```

The extra function basically waits 0 milliseconds and then continues with the queue, which seems to keep the animation from being called immediately. It doesn't work without .delay() though...

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for answering on an semi-old question!  You're definitely on to something, but it's not quite working - now I don't have the problem where it just disappears after a few seconds, rather it is consistently fading out like I want... however, it seems like if I wait about 5 seconds before pressing OK, it waits for about 3 seconds to fade out, if I wait for 10 it waits for about 8.  If I press it right away it works right away.  So there's something going on with the queue I guess, any idea??  I think we might be close, again, thanks!  Great troubleshooting so far!

Answer (score 0):

Do you still get the issue if you remove the reference to jquery.tablednd_0_5.js?

What about if you change the event bind function to:

```
$(".removeQuestion").live("click", function(){
    //rest of previous function content
});
```

Comment: As of jQuery 1.7, the .live() method is deprecated. Use .on() to attach event handlers (http://api.jquery.com/live).

Comment: Thanks @KeesC.Bakker for your input.  I did try removing the tablednd code but no dice.  I even tried .live just to see, but same bugs.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't got a Mac, so I can't really see if it is a "Mac" problem. I've looked at your code and rewritten it somewhat to make it reuse some stuff:

```
$('#questions .removeQuestion').on('click', function() {

        var element = $(this).closest('tr');

        if (confirm('Are you sure you want to remove this question?')) {

            var nrOfQuestions = $('#questions tr').length;    

            if (nrOfQuestions == 1) {
                element.find('textarea').val('');
                element.find('input[type=radio]').removeAttr('checked');
            }
            else {
                element.fadeOut(300, function() {
                        element.remove();
                });

                // update total questions text
                $('.total_questions').text(nrOfQuestions - 1);
            }
    }
});
```

Notes:

1. I'm saving the clicked row to process later - I've used a `closest` to get the nearest 'parent'.
2. `Find` operations can be done to find child elements in the entire sub tree
3. Recalculate number of questions every time (reuse previous result)
4. The click will fire on the remove link, not on the #questions table.

Comment: Thanks again, but still no luck.  Your code is definitely cleaner, but sadly I have the same problem.  Also, just to note, your format of the `.on` didn't add the event handler to newly added table rows - it needs to have the `.removeQuestion` as the selector to be a delegated event as per the second to last example on http://api.jquery.com/on/.

Comment: @jeff when I look at the documentation http://api.jquery.com/on/ I see that the selector is optional. The old `live` statement worked without an extra selector as well, so I don't know if you are right about the `on`. Maybe it is a good idea to create an example in http://www.jsfiddle.net

Comment: thanks for still looking into this.  You are right, the selector is optional, but I need to use it because only existing DOM elements at the time `.on` gets called get the click handler applied to them.  This means than any additional table rows that I add don't get the click handler unless I use event delegation by setting the optional selector argument in `.on`.  Your suggested way works fine for existing table rows, just not for new ones.  Using the selector makes it work for all rows added at anytime.
Unfortunately, none of this seems to affect my bug though with `.fadeOut`.